# Invoke Python as Executable

Tags: python, linux

I have a Python script, a simple Hello, World. I need to invoke it as I would an executable and take piped input:

```
./myprogram < myinput
```

How do I generate the command `python3 myprogram.py` and handle the piped input?

Comment: You add the shebang line at the top of your script `#!/usr/bin/python` and then invoke `./myprogram.py`. If you're on windows, good luck.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Perfect, thank you! If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The shebang, as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ pointed out  and do `chmod +x myprogram `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a *Nix system, you'll need to follow 3 steps:

1. Make sure your script has executable permissions

   ```
   chmod +x myprogram.py
   ```
2. Add the shebang line to the top of your script

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   ```

   As pointed out in the comments, `/usr/bin/env python3` makes it easier to work with venvs and other local installations of python.
3. Invoke the script with

   ```
   ./myprogram.py < myinput
   ```

To handle the input, you will need to `import sys` in your script, and then read from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) remove the sudo if it is not needed. 2) use ``/usr/bin/env python``. This will make working with virtual environments and other local installations of python much easier later.

Comment: The OP actually wanted to execute the script with `python3`. Presumably `/usr/bin/python` is python 2.

Comment: @khelwood I'm not sure what the python3 path is on nix. On my mac, it's `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6`. Any hints?

Comment: You can use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and it should find the correct executable.

Comment: A nitpick - this doesn't answer OP's second question _"How do I ... handle the piped input?"_. I suggest adding a step `4.` with reading from `sys.stdin` to handle the input.

Comment: @zwer Thanks, edited and CW'd, this answer has contributions from at least 3 users now :p

Comment: I used `#!/usr/bin/python3` on my system.